# Reverse Engineering transformation from C# using Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect, mda

I know that it will sound odd but I need to create a reverse process of MDA  going from PSM -> PIM or in similar notion.
I have C# package which is responsible for creating XML messages. Until know it work fine as all development was in C# and the component was reused. But we are currently starting developing under different platforms and we would like to have some contract specified first - XSD schema. So I did reverse engineer the current package and tried to generate xsd. But several problems occurred which I need to solve:

- translation of C# collection classes to relations
- moving inner classes to package
- converting C# properties to attributes
- I am not quite sure how should I model C# Dictionary with

I am aware of that process is far away from ideal and should work opposite direction but I can hardly fight against at least at the moment.

Any hints appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to write custom transformation as Code to potential PIM is not a one-to-one mapping but one-to-many mapping.
There is a need to convert data types, properties, etc.

I sorted this way and it works for the purpose I needed.